# How can I replace text in html using a bash script

Tags: linux, variables, startup

I am using a startup script with a managed instance group in Google Cloud GCE. In the script I want to find out the zone that the instance is in and then insert that zone in the **index.html** file, among other things.

What is not working in the script is the part where it retrieves the zone name, puts in a variable and then replaces a placeholder in **index.html**.

Here is the part of the script that does not work:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
...
...
MYZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list |grep my-instance |awk -F'[ ]' '{print $3}')
sed -i "s/%%zone%%/$MYZONE/" index.html
```

In the **index.html** the placeholder looks like:

```
you are on a server in %%zone%%
```

If I execute these commands in terminal window (once the instance is built), they all work as expected, but in the startup script they do not.

All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "startup script." Where/how is this script being called?

Comment: It is possible that this "startup script" does not have the same session variables as an interactive shell. I would start by using full paths to `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, as well as, `index.html`. It would likely help to have the "startup script" write some temp log files containing the output of different parts of your complex command. Break the command apart into pieces and debug.

Comment: Also remove the space in the shebang line. `#!/bin/bash`, not `#! /bin/bash`. I prefer defining PATH in my scripts rather than fully qualifying paths to multiple commands. Wondering if `gcloud` is installed in a location not in the usual default PATH.